# How to iterate over a list of characters and manipluate the characters in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to go through a list of characters in a list and do something to the current character. My java equivalent of what I am trying to accomplish is:

```
public class MyClass {
    void repeat(String s) {
        String newString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
          newString += s.charAt(i);
          newString += s.charAt(i);
        }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyClass test = new MyClass();
    test.repeat("abc");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at list comprehensions and try to write a haskell function to do this

Comment: Also have a look at the Prelude `concat` function, or just use recursion

Answer (score 2):

One of the nicest thing about functional programming is that patterns like yours can be encapsulated in one higher-order function; if nothing fits, you can still use recursion.

## Recursion

First up, a simple recursive solution. The idea behind this is that it's like a for-loop:

```
recursiveFunction [] = baseCase
recursiveFunction (char1:rest) = (doSomethingWith char1) : (recursiveFunction rest)
```

So let's write your `repeat` function in this form. What is the base case? Well, if you `repeat` an empty string, you'll get an empty string back. What is the recursion? In this case, we're doubling the first character, then recursing along the rest of the string. So here's a recursive solution:

```
repeat1 [] = []
repeat1 (c:cs) = c : c : (repeat1 cs)
```

## Higher-order Functions

As you start writing more Haskell, you'll discover that these sort of recursive solutions often fit into a few repetitive patterns. Luckily, the standard library contains several predefined recursive functions for these sort of patterns:

- `fmap` is used to map each element of a list to a different value using a function given as a parameter. For example, `fmap (\x -> x + 1)` adds `1` to each element of a list. Unfortunately, it can't change the length of a list, so we can't use `fmap` by itself.
- `concat` is used to 'flatten' a nested list. For example, `concat [[1,2],[3,4,5]]` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
- `foldr`/`foldl` are two more complex and generic functions. For more details, consult [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds).

None of these seem to directly fit your needs. However, we can use `concat` and `fmap` together:

```
repeat2 list = concat $ fmap (\x -> [x,x]) list
```

The idea is that `fmap` changes e.g. `[1,2,3]` to a nested list `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`, which concat then flattens. This pattern of generating multiple elements from a single one is so common that the combination even has a special name: `concatMap`. You use it like so:

```
repeat3 list = concatMap (\x -> [x,x]) list
```

Personally, this is how I'd write `repeat` in Haskell. (Well, *almost*: I'd use *eta-reduction* to simplify it slightly more. But at your level that's irrelevant.) This is why Haskell in my opinion is so much more powerful than many other languages: this 7-line Java method is one line of highly readable, idiomatic Haskell!

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, it's probably wise to start with a list comprehension:

```
-- | Repeat each element of a list twice.
double :: [x] -> [x]
double xs = [d | x <- xs, d <- [x, x]]
```

But the fact that the second list in the comprehension always has the same number of elements, regardless of the value of `x`, means that we don't need quite that much power: the `Applicative` interface is sufficient. Let's start by writing the comprehension a bit differently:

```
double xs = xs >>= \x -> [x, x] >>= \d -> pure d
```

We can simplify immediately using a monad identity law:

```
double xs = xs >>= \x -> [x, x]
```

Now we switch over to `Applicative`, but let's leave a hole for the hard part:

```
double :: [x] -> [x]
double xs = liftA2 _1 xs [False, True]
```

The compiler lets us know that

```
_1 :: x -> Bool -> x
```

Since the elements of the inner/second list are always the same, and always come from the current outer/first list element, we don't have to care about the `Bool`:

```
double xs = liftA2 const xs [False, True]
```

Indeed, we don't even need to be *able* to distinguish the list positions:

```
double xs = liftA2 const xs [(),()]
```

Of course, we have a special `Applicative` method, `(<*)`, that corresponds to `liftA2 const`, so let's use it:

```
double xs = xs <* [(),()]
```

And then, if we like, we can avoid mentioning `xs` by switching to a "point-free" form:

```
-- | Repeat each element of a list twice.
double :: [x] -> [x]
double = (<* [(),()])
```

Now for the test:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ double [1..3]
```

This will print `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`.

---

`double` admits a slight generalization of dubious value:

```
double :: Alternative f => f x -> f x
double = (<* join (<|>) (pure ()))
```

This will work for sequences as well as lists:

```
double (Data.Sequence.fromList [1..3]) = Data.Sequence.fromList [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

but it could be a bit confusing for some other `Alternative` instances:

```
double (Just 3) = Just 3
```

Comment: Clever solution! I would never have thought of using `(<*)`. But I can't help but think that this is a bit of overkill for such a simple problem - as mentioned in my answer, I would go with `concatMap (\x -> [x,x])`.

Comment: @bradrn, I think that would be an entirely reasonable choice!